# Подскажите исчерпывающий материал по Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Приходилось работать с EFCore в учебном проекте, до сих знаком лишь с материалом, найденном на Metanit. SQL знаю на хорошем уровне.

Хотел бы узнать, есть ли в открытом доступе какой-нибудь курс/учебник, затрагивающий как можно больше аспектов использования EF?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/ ?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/category/entity-framework/